# Jasper Report : "Document has no pages"

Tags: javascript, java, jasper-reports

I have a problem when I run this code. I get always this message : "Document has no pages" with a blank page in the pdf file .

Note: I'm using NetBeans IDE 7.2 Beta.

Jar files imported are:

- com.lowagie.text-2.1.7.jar
- commons-beanutils-1.5.jar
- commons-collections-2.1.jar
- commons-digester-2.1.jar
- commons-javaflow.jar
- commons-logging-1.3.jar
- jasperreports-5.5.1.jar
- javax.servlet.jar

I need your help,please.

this is my code :

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.Currency;
import java.util.HashMap;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport;
import net.sf.jasperreports.swing.JRViewer;


public class Report extends JFrame{


   public Report(String month,int year){

                    try{
                        //load the driver
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/motor";
                String user="root";
                String pass="";

                Connection cn=DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pass);
                System.out.println("connected in report");
                PreparedStatement ps = cn.prepareStatement("select number,title,name,ikar,echtirak,price,tarakom from users order by number asc");
                ResultSet rs;
                rs=ps.executeQuery();

                 JasperPrint jasperPrint=null;
               HashMap<String, Object> mapParameters = new HashMap <String, Object>();

             // jrxml compiling process

           JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("C:/Users/user/Documents/NetBeansProjects/MotorApp/MyReports/motorReport.jrxml");
           int i=1;
                while(rs.next()){

                 mapParameters.put("Name", rs.getString("title")+" "+rs.getString("name"));
                 mapParameters.put("Number",rs.getString("number"));
                 mapParameters.put("Ikar",rs.getString("ikar"));
                 mapParameters.put("Amperage",rs.getString("echtirak")+" A");
                 mapParameters.put("tarakom",rs.getString("tarakom")+" $");
                 mapParameters.put("monthPrice",rs.getString("price")+" $");

                 Integer total=Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("price"))+Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("tarakom"));
                 mapParameters.put("totalPrice",total+" $");
                 mapParameters.put("monthYear",year+" "+month);


                 try{

                System.out.println("Filling report...");
                jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, mapParameters,cn);
                JRViewer viewer = new JRViewer(jasperPrint);
                 System.out.println("Done!");
                JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint,"C:/Users/user/Desktop/"+month+" "+year+".pdf");

                 }catch(JRException elle){
                     System.out.println(elle.getMessage());
                 }

                 }

             }catch(Exception ev){
                 System.out.println(ev.getMessage());
             }

   }


}
```

I truly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is on the motorReport.jrxml file. It may have some issues on its content. Try reducing the contents of the report to a point where the code works and the reports can display properly. It may give you a clue to the cause of the problem. Then get back here with more specifics if you still can't solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

mapParameters in your code is not records of DataSource. It is parameters of report, therefore report haven't records.

One of the possible solutions: convert ResultSet into BeanCollection, make JRBeanCollectionDataSource and pass it into fillReport.

Make bean for saving result of query.

```
public class UserBean {
private String name;

public String getName() {
  return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
  this.name = name;
}
.... 

}
```

For example result is

```
List myList = new ArrayList<UserBean>();
```

Convert into collection example here [stackoverflow.com/questions/17206523/put-resultset-values-into-collection-object-then-add-to-arraylist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17206523/put-resultset-values-into-collection-object-then-add-to-arraylist)

After convert you must call fillReport like this:

```
 jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, new HashMap<String,Object>, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(myList));
```